# Angular ng-repeat with mixed elements

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert a form that is using .Net MVC to using Angular. I'm trying to use ng-repeat to produce the input fields within the form. Which this is working as expected. But, I need select fields mixed in with the text input fields.

How do I go about mixing text fields and select fields within one form using ng-repeat? Is it even possible? I'm new to Angular as well. This code is just a very quick example and will be cleaned up and properly structured.

```html
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-init="profiles = [
       {id: 'first-name', label: 'First Name', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'middle-name', label: 'Middle Name', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'last-name', label: 'Last Address', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'suffix', label: 'Suffix', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'social-security-number', label: 'Social Security Number', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'DateOfBirth1', label: 'Date of Birth', class: 'datePicker hasDatepicker valid', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'years-in-school', label: 'Years in School', type: 'text'},
       {id: 'marital-status', label: 'Marital Status', type: 'select'}
     ]">
    <h2>Borrowers Information</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-repeat="profile in profiles" class="control-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="{{profile.id}}">{{profile.label}}</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a valid first name." id="{{profile.id}}" name="{{profile.id}}" value="" type="{{profile.type}}" class="{{profile.class}}">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the angular ng-switch or ng-if for the type and add your select options as an array in your form object like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/82u6gj26/

### Angular

```
vm.person = {};
vm.form = [{
    type:'text',
    label:'First Name',
    id:'first_name'
},
{
    type:'select',
    label:'Marital Status',
    id:'marital_status',
    options:[
        {id:'Single',name:'Single'},
        {id:'Married',name:'Married'}
    ]}
];
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="form in ctrl.form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{form.label}}</label>
        <div ng-switch="form.type">
            <input
                type="text"
                ng-switch-when="text"
                ng-model="ctrl.person[form.id]">

            <select
                ng-switch-when="select"
                ng-model="ctrl.person[form.id]"
                ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in form.options">
                <option>Select One</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

For example:

```
...
<div class="controls">
 <input ng-if="profile.type != 'select'">
 <select ng-if="profile.type == 'select'">
 </select>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this possible,

```
    <div ng-repeat="profile in profiles" class="control-group col-md-3">
          <label class="control-label" for="{{profile.id}}">{{profile.label}}</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a valid first name." id="{{profile.id}}" name="{{profile.id}}" value="" type="{{profile.type}}" class="{{profile.class}}" ng-if="{{profile.type!='select'}}">
            <select id="{{profile.id}}" name="{{profile.id}}" class="{{profile.class}}" ng-if="{{profile.type=='select'}}">
             <option value="{{option.value}}" ng-repeat="option in profile.options">{{option.caption}}</option>
</select>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

use ng-if or ng-show to which element to display